# display:table-row does not work in browsers except FireFox

Tags: html, css

I am using this code which works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome, Edge, IE11. The problem seems to be related to `display:table-row`.
The yellow sidebar with the red buttons should stay at the same height of the green area. This is true in FireFox but not eslewhere.

Is there anyway I can change it to make it more supported?

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:table;
}

#titleContainer{
  display:table-row;
  background-color: blue;
}

#contentContainer{
  display:table-row;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index:1000;
}

#sidebar > ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:40px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
}

#sidebar > ul + ul {
  bottom:0;
}

#sidebar > ul > li {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
  background-color: red;
}

#page{
  background-color: green;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleContainer">
  <center>
  <h2>
  TITLE
  </h2>
  </center>
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
  <li>TOP</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>BOTTOM</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="page"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: center tags are obsolete and should not be used, but the problem is if you are wanting to use table row, then it should be inside something with display table, and have a child that is display table-cell - not sure why you need it in this scenario - why are you changing the display at all?

Comment: If you want to keep the table behaviour, throw away the `position` properties. Table cells and positioning don't play well together. Also, don't use nested tables.

Comment: @Pete an accepted SO answer I cannot find now stated that it is a good way deal with dynamic div sizes (in my case the title and the rest below)

Comment: @MrLister unfortunately, I should not change sidebar css (it's in an external project). Although I can still overwrite its css, I am interested in understanding how can I solve the problem. I will update the question with these info asap.

Comment: Then insert a new div in the `contentContainer`, make it a `table-cell` and put the `sidebar` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I achieved the same functionality as in my example, but with support for the other browsers as well by removing the `display:table` and using `display:flex` instead. My main problems were actually (I should have explained myself better I must admint):

- I had to have two divs, one on another, which should take together whole the page height and whose height are dynamic
- I cannot touch the `.sidebar` css, as it is an external project I'd better not change.

So my final code is this one, thanks both to @MrLister and @Pete for the precioud feedback (I removed the obsolete `<center>` tag as suggested by @Pete):

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

#titleContainer{
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

#contentContainer{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index:1000;
}

#sidebar > ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:40px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
}

#sidebar > ul + ul {
  bottom:0;
}

#sidebar > ul > li {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
  background-color: red;
}

#page{
  background-color: green;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleContainer">
  <h2>
  TITLE
  </h2>
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
  <li>TOP</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>BOTTOM</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="page"></div>
</div>
```